# how can I convert colors including alpha channel in GraphicsMagick?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I have a PNG image.  I want to use GraphicsMagick to convert all pixels with RGBA=(0, 0, 0, 0) (transparent over black) to be RGBA=(255, 255, 255, 0) (transparent over white).  Is it possible to do this in GraphicsMagick?

my current command is:

```
gm convert orig.png -fill "#FFFFFF00" -opaque "#00000000" result.png
```

however, this doesn't work because for some reason the alpha channel on the replacement gets set to 100%.  So, the actual fill ends up being #FFFFFFFF.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

this worked:

```
gm convert orig.png -fill "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)" -opaque "#00000000" result.png
```

looks like the "#FFFFFF00" is properly recognized by the opaque param but not by the fill param